# OCaml print statements

Tags: printing, syntax, ocaml

Is it possible to put print statements for debugging/testing in blocks of code?

For example, in Java you can use `System.out.println("")` in the middle of methods to check variables or other things.

But in OCaml, would a command like `print_string` work? Wouldn't it return a value of type unit, thus causing an error, instead of allowing you to print it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You will be fine if you embed the print in an [expression sequence](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora028.html).

**UPDATE**

Here is a concrete example, because the answer above was rather short and, well, answers with links only are not good answers. It is the classic tail-recursive formulation of factorial (yeah, boring, but familiar):

```
# let fac n =
  let rec f i n acc =
    if i >= n
    then acc
    else (Printf.printf "%8d%8d%8d\n" i n acc; f (i+1) n ((i+1)*acc))
  in
    f 0 n 1;;
val fac : int -> int = <fun>
# fac 5;;
       0       5       1
       1       5       1
       2       5       2
       3       5       6
       4       5      24
- : int = 120
```

Here you can see the side-effects of the print, but the result still turned out to be 120 as expected.

Comment: Great, thank you so much! This was exactly what I was looking for. Are expression sequences usually used for anything else, or is this the main usage of them? I guess you can also use it to change values of variables?

Comment: Yes, anything that requires updating state, such as updating the value of references, is generally handled this way.  There is a very nice and detailed discussion of this [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora028.html), see the section "Sequence".

Answer (score 13):

Since OCaml isn't a *pure* functional language, there are many ways to do this.  Here is the way I write this kind of code, just for a concrete example.

```
let rec mylength list =
(* DEBUG *)
let () = Printf.printf "mylength here, null list: %b\n%!" (list = [])
in
(* DEBUG *)
    match list with
    | [] -> 0
    | _ :: rest -> 1 + mylength rest
```

After it works you can remove the stuff inside the (* DEBUG *) comments.

Note the use of %! to flush the buffer.  If you do a lot of debugging with `printf` (as I do), it's really useful to learn about this.

Comment: it would be simpler to write `(* DEBUG *)
Printf.printf "mylength here, null list: %b\n%!" (list = []);
(* DEBUG *)`

Comment: Sure; like I said I'm just showing the way I really write it.  I'm shy about using semicolons outside of parens because of the many precedences I have left to learn.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a simple example that shows that expression sequences as mentioned in [Ray Toal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382002/ocaml-print-statements#7382040) don't necessarily need parentheses around them:

```
let get_a_string =
  let a_string = "a string" in
  (* The semicolon causes the return value of the statement to be discarded *)
  Printf.printf "Debug: %s\n" a_string;
  a_string

let () = Printf.printf "Result: %s\n" get_a_string
```

Another way to discard a function's return value is [`ignore`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Stdlib.html#VALignore):

```
ignore (Printf.printf "Debug info");
```